# update/clear fields automatically or by event etc. by specific date

Tags: php, javascript, date

hi im new to programming
 i have this small system for room reservations (school requirement). i have this question that is it possible to update the fields of my table on specific date? for example is today is 2010-10-14. if the field matches on the same date. it will clear/update my field automatically?

i dont really know where to start with this. looking forward for your help. thanks

-renz

Comment: What do you mean "this small system" and "update the fields"? What kind of system and what kind of fields? Please be more specific and if possible, show some sources too.

Comment: i have said room reservations. i have three tables naming users , reservations, and rooms. i want to update the field of the rooms on specific date, like if the date_out in the rooms table is the same as the sysdate it will update the status field from unavailable to available and make the room available again for choosing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a daily cronjob and run this script:

```
$sql = "UPDATE rooms SET status = 'passed' WHERE date_field = '2010-10-14'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result) 
  print 'update okay'
```

Comment: can i make this on function onLoad ?